# How can I set a var for the url in libcurl

Tags: c++, libcurl

I followed a tutorial to fetch a webpage. It worked but they manually set the URL.
I tried changing it to use a URL from a var, but that did not work.
I get an error in the terminal
"Couldn't resolve host name"
I tried main(char*) which gave the same error.
I can't seem to find anything online for this.
How can I make it so a user-defined var can be used as the URL?

code below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  string website;

  getline(cin, website);

  CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();

  if (!curl) {
    fprintf(stderr, "init failed\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  // set up

  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "$website");

  // perform
  CURLcode result = curl_easy_perform(curl);
  if (result != CURLE_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "download prob: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(result));
  }

  curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, website.c_str());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"$website"` is just a string, a piece of text. The variable should be referenced as `website`, and since the function is expecting a pointer to an array of characters, you use the `c_str()` or `data()` method of the class.

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, website.data());
```